# Convergent $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n \log^n(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove that this series is convergent:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n \log^n(n)}$$

I'm having problems with the limit for the ratio test, and I've already tried the comparision test and to integrate the function.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: The comparison test works if you choose the right sequence to compare to. Any idea what you could try?

Comment: Everything I came up with were lower bounds, and I need an upper one... but I´ll keep thinking :)

Comment: Is that $\log^n$ an iteration or a repeated multiplication?

Comment: @JackM I'm sorry, but what's the difference? (I'm Spanish, not quite familiar with the English math terms)

Comment: Sometimes people write $\log^n(x)$ when they mean $(\log x)^n$, and sometimes (probably other) people write that when they mean $\underbrace{\log(\log(\cdots\cdots(\log(x))\cdots)}_{n}$.  Which one is intended here?

Comment: The first one (I'm assuming that's the repeated multiplication). Did I write it wrong? My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** comparison test with
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}
$$
In order to show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}$ converges, use the integral test.

**Hint for the integral:** $u$ substitution with $u = \log(x)$

Comment: You should compare to $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\log (n))^2}$ - the integral test for $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n}$ blows up like $\log \log x$.

Comment: @Batman yes, that's what I meant.  Good catch!

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try: $$\frac{1}{n\log^n n}< \frac{1}{2^n}$$ for $n>e^2$.